# django npm and node packages architecture

Tags: python, node.js, django, npm, architecture

On the project I am joining this is the architecture for the `node_packages`:

```
|- Django project
|-- app1
|-- app2
|-- node_modules
|--- foundation-sites
|--- grunt
|-- static
|--- css
|--- images
|--- js
|--urls.py
|--settings.py
|--package.json
```

I personally think `node_packages` should be in the static under the `js` folder as well as the `package.json` like so:

```
|- Django project
|-- app1
|-- app2
|-- static
|--- css
|--- images
|--- js
|---- node_modules
|----- foundation-sites
|----- grunt
|---- packages.json
|--urls.py
|--settings.py
```

is there a difference? which is best practice? why?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I understand your thinking of wanting to keep all the javascript related files in one place, but here are a couple of reasons you might want to keep the `node_modules` folder and the `package.json` file out of a Django app's `static` directory.

1. **You'll likely end up statically serving files that aren't meant to be.** If the `node_modules` folder exists in your production environment, running `collectstatic` will have to check that it's in sync every time, which can be slow due to nodes nested dependency structure. And assuming you have a build step to bundle and transpile your JS, if those source files are within `static`, they too will be served as static files, for no reason.
2. **You might want to use node for more than just your JavaScript build process.** I see you're using Grunt, and you may want to use it to for more than your JavaScript needs, like minifying your `css`, or running a proxy server around your Django dev server that auto-reloads your browser when files change or the Django server restarts. With this in mind, it might make more sense to think of Node.js as a tool in your build process that could touch any part of your project, the bundling/transpiling of JavaScript being only one part of that.

Comment: I think this is the best answer but I am starting to wonder why not put it outside of the project at all?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I tried to answer the question from the angle of how not to structure things because when it comes to project structure, it really depends on your project. For instance I have some Django projects that are completely API driven React/Redux based apps. With projects like that, I tend to like to pull out the front-end stuff completely into its own repo and host it separately. In projects that use Django's templating system it usually makes more sense to me to have it with the Django project itself.

Comment: Why does it make no sense tho? Django templates can wrap around React projects, and in some cases (like admin pages), you'd want access to those npm packages

Answer (score 22):

- Put `node_modules` and `package.json` at the top level of your project:

  - easily accessible, you install modules and run commands at the top level of your project
  - dependencies exposed at the top level, commonly alongside pip requirements
  - external libraries/modules separated from your code
- Add `node_modules` to `.gitignore`
- Serve only generated files. Keep your source code outside `STATICFILES_DIRS`
- (Optional) If you want to serve some npm modules without vendoring (instead of bower) use a tool like [django-npm](https://github.com/kevin1024/django-npm) to specify what will be exposed

Example projects:

https://github.com/mbrochh/django-reactjs-boilerplate

https://github.com/Seedstars/django-react-redux-base

Comment: Although I voted up to your answer since it will help people that are new to the setup you did not answer my question which is "why" and not "how"

Comment: What's vendoring?

Comment: Vendoring is basically copying 3rd party packages into your project.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out [django-npm](https://github.com/kevin1024/django-npm), it's an excellent project. I wish I discovered it earlier!

Answer (score 7):

In general the `node_modules` should be outside of the Django application. The typical format I use for a Django application is the following:

```
- AppName
---- appname (This is the Django Project)
---- appname-env (Python virtualenv)
---- bower_components
---- bower.json
---- gulpfile.js
---- node_modules
---- package.json
---- requirements.txt
```

Then I use gulp to copy the components from either node modules or bower components into my app `static/lib` directory.

Comment: Why do you think it should be outside of the application? I don't think that it's a general thing. Besides that that is a good and new idea to approach node.js with django

Comment: I think the primary reason is that only files that are to be served to the client should reside in your projects static folder. There is no reason to have excess and unnecessary files being available to client.