# How to add link to npm package to a django template using the script tag when path is always converted to a url

Tags: javascript, django, url, npm, directory

I am trying to add a link to a folder in the npm_modules folder located in the root of my Django project to one of my templates. However, when attempting to do so, the path typed in is simply appended to the current url and is treated as a link. Since my folder is not there, it is not loaded and my javascript crashes.

Since it is best practice to keep the npm_modules folder in root, how do I go about referencing folders within it inside my templates?

```
<script src="\node_modules\angular-file-upload\dist\angular-file- 
upload.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep your npm package file in `static` folder. Then in template

```
{% load staticfiles %}
...
<script src="{% static node_modules\angular-file-upload\dist\angular-file- 
upload.min.js %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Assume you save your `angular-file-upload.min.js` in folder `static/node_modules/angular-file-upload/dist`

In `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: This was my first thought however when i was doing some research I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966065/django-npm-and-node-packages-architecture) where multiple people were recommending we leave it in the root instead of static. Currently, I just said screw it and put it in the static but is it best practice?